# Operators &= and ~1U in C

Tags: c, operators

What does this piece of code do `s &= ~1U` if `s=8`?
I assume that it has to do something with binary, but dont know what exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the type of `s`.  Post its type.

Comment: The operation unsets the bit 0. Since it wasn't set in 8, then it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here I write it out in 1-byte binary (8 digits) for simplicity.

```
s = s & ~1            // U means "unsigned"
s = 8 & ~(0b00000001) // Here is the binary representation of 1
s = 8 & 0b11111110    // ~1 is 254
s = 0b00001000 & 0b11111110
s = 0b00001000

s == 8  // Final Answer.
```

This is confirmed by running the code on [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/2ugIZo)

#### Input

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int s = 8;
    s &= ~1U;
    printf("%d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
8
```